# if-not condition fails (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

http://jsbin.com/zexix/1/

```
$(function() {

    if ( !$(".first.last") ) {
      console.log("div with both first and last classes does not exists")
    } else {
      console.log("it exists");
    }

});
```

I want to check if a div with both `first` and `last` classes DOES NOT exist, but the check fails.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to check the number of elements found, as jQuery returns an empty collection in the event of no elements being found (which evaluates to a truthy value in the if statement):

```
if ( !$(".first.last").length )
```

I'd suggest testing against 0 explicitly, rather than relying on a falsey value, though:

```
if ( $(".first.last").length === 0 )
```

Comment: Ah, silly mistakes happen with working late night (3am) here.

Comment: Happens to all of us. :)

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways:

#### 1.  check the length:

```
if ( !$(".first.last").length ) { // check the length if none returns 0 == false
```

#### 2. check the visibility:

```
if ( !$(".first.last").is(':visible') ) { // returns boolean true/false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this by checking the first object that is returned from JQuery:

```
if (!$(".first.last")[0]){
    console.log("div with both first and last classes does not exists");
} else {
  console.log("it exists");
}
```